# C# Constraint for type inheriting over generic type

Tags: c#, generics

I want to create an interface for classes that will operate on data implementing generic interface, but I'm unable to create a constraint for it to limit type to implementation of that generic.

IData:

```
public interface IData<T> where T: class
{
    T Data { get; set; }
}
```

So I'll have implementation like this

```
public class AData : IData<string>
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

With that I want to create class that handles creation of that data

```
public class ADataGenerator : IDataGenerator<AData> 
{
   AData Generate(...);
}
```

And also uses it

```
public class AHandler : IHandler<AData>
{
    public void Handle(AData data)
}
```

How should IDataGenerator and IHandler definitions look to make this work nad limit types to IData, simultaneously allowing them to be returned from factories as above interfaces?
Such restrictions are forbidden:

```
public interface IDataGenerator<T> where T : IData
public interface IDataGenerator<T> where T : IData<>
```

Comment: What is the interface supposed to restrict to? Given an IDataGenerator<T> you only get a T generated, in which case restricting on IData<U> doesn't gain much,  or do you want to use a generator with any IData<U>, in which case covariance might help?

Comment: I want to be able to specify generators and handlers for concrete implementation of IData, To make sure AData can only be used in AGenerator and AHandler.

Comment: Then what do you gain by restricting the type of T in IDataGenerator<T>? You can do it by adding a second parameter, interface IDataGenerator<T, U> where T : IData<U>, but if your intention is only to use the concrete type T it doesn't seem worth it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/grammar trace through type_parameter_constraints_clause you have a type_name not a unbound_type_name so it has to have at least one argument in the '<>'

Comment: You are right, I can do it by adding second parameter, but then it loose all the sense ;/ I want to use 3 interfaces to easily create sets of 3 classes - XData, XGenerator and XHandler that depends on each other.

Comment: Ok, I think I just will go with marker interfaces and then validate instance types provided to methods.

Comment: `public interface IDataGenerator<T> where T : IData<T>` maybe?